# Adding listener to MessageBox ok button in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, messagebox

I used `MessageBox` in that manner:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {

                MessageBox.Show("The alarm has been raised");
            });
```

How to take an action after user taps ok?

Comment: The `MessageBox.Show` method returns a `MessageBoxResult` variable, which indicates what action was taken (OK, Cancel, None, Yes or No). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598690(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference of Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices in your project.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            List<string> messageboxitm = new List<string>();
            messageboxitm.Add("Yes");
            messageboxitm.Add("No");
            IAsyncResult result = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Message", "The alarm has been raised", messageboxitm, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Alert, new AsyncCallback(OnMessageBoxClosed), null);

});
 private void OnMessageBoxClosed(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int? buttonIndex = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(ar);
            switch (buttonIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                   //Do your work
                    break;               
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Accepted as most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

In simple situations you can use `MessageBoxResult` (under Windows Phone limited only to Buttons OK / OKCancel):

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Show next message?", "Question", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
   // code after user click
   if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK) MessageBox.Show("Yeah");
});
```

But it is little limited and you cannot change buttons content. Your solution using [Guide.BeginShowMessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide.beginshowmessagebox.aspx) is more configurable. You can also use other solutions: [CustomMessageBox from Windows Phone Toolkit](http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/) and if you have Telerik - [RadMessageBox](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/messagebox-gettingstarted-overview.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
        IAsyncResult result =Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(
"Info",
"Alarm has been raised",
new string[] { "OK", "Call emergency" },
0,
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.MessageBoxIcon.None,
null,
null);

       result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        media.AutoPlay = true;
    }
```